# SpriteKit: add UIGestureRecognizer and detect which node was swiped

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

In which method do I add a `UIGestureRecognizer` to my `SKScene`. And how do I detect which node was swiped? This doesn't seem to work:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

    ...

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
    recognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
    [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];

    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: note that the older answers here while generally correct contain some stuff that has become broken

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You add the `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` in this method:

```
- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
    recognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
    [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
}
```

And that's how you detect which `SKNode` was swiped:

```
- (void)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        CGPoint touchLocation = [sender locationInView:sender.view];
        touchLocation = [self convertPointFromView:touchLocation];
        SKSpriteNode *touchedNode = (SKSpriteNode *)[self nodeAtPoint:touchLocation];

        NSLog(@"%@", touchedNode);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works fine! And don't forget about reversing of Y axis in sprite-kit

Comment: you don't actually need to reverse it, in this setting. the convertors seem to do it.

Answer (score 5):

Swift 3 version inspired by S.E.'s answer:

```
func didSceneViewPan(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == .began {

        let touchPoint = sender.location(in: sender.view)
        let touchLocation = convertPoint(fromView: touchPoint)

        if isPointInNode(point: touchLocation, node: testNode) { 
            print("yes, node touched!")
        } else {
            print("no bueno :(")
        }
     }
 }


fileprivate func isPointInNode(point: CGPoint, node: SKNode) -> Bool {
    // Get all nodes intersecting <point>
    let nodes = self.nodes(at: point)

    // Return true on first one that matches <node>
    for n in nodes {
        if n == node {
            return true
        }
    }

    // If here, <point> not inside <node> so return false
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 5):

## For 2017...

Say you have a scene with various sprites.

Tap on one of them. You need to know which one was tapped ...

```
class YourScene: SKScene {
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        
        super.didMove(to: view)
        
        // your setup for the scene - example, add objects etc
        
        setupTapDetection()
    }
    
    func setupTapDetection() {
        
        let t = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped(_:)))
        view?.addGestureRecognizer(t)
    }
    
    @objc func tapped(_ tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        
        // critical...
        if tap.state != .ended { return }
        
        // Note: you actually do NOT "invert the Y axis",
        // these two calls in fact take care of that properly.
        let viewPoint = tap.location(in: tap.view)
        let scenePoint = convertPoint(fromView: viewPoint)
        
        // technically there could be more than one node...
        let nn = nodes(at: scenePoint)
        
        if nn.count == 0 {
            
            print("you very like tapped 'nowhere'")
            return
        }
        
        if nn.count != 1 {
            
            // in almost all games or physics scenes,
            // it is not possible this would happen
            print("something odd happened - overlapping nodes?")
            return
        }
        
        // you must have a custom class for your sprites
        // Say it is class YourSprites: SKSpriteNode
      
        if let dotSpriteTapped = nn.first! as? YourSprites {
            
            // we are done. dotSpriteTapped is the YourSprite,
            // which was tapped. now do whatever you want.
            
            let nm = String(describing: dotSpriteTapped.name)
            print("   \(nm)")
            
            // you can now access your own properties:
            
            let whichTank = dotSpriteTapped.someID
            print("   \(whichTank)")
            
            let tankPower = dotSpriteTapped.sheildStrength
            print("   \(tankPower)")
        }
    }
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

You can check of the nodes at a location include a node you're looking for using this:

```
nodes(at: touchLocation).contains(nodeYouAreLookingFor)
```